# Use Vectors To Show Three Vertices Belong to a Right Triangle

Tags: linear-algebra, geometry, vector-spaces

**The Full Question**

[image]

**Theorems Used**

This is what I call theorem 1:

[image]

**My Work**

This problem has two major steps as far as I can see. First, I must show that these are points of a triangle(not specifically a right triangle). Second, I will use theorem $1$ to show that there exists a $90$ degree angle between two of my vectors, which means my triangle is right angle triangle.

**Where I Am Having Difficulty**

The second step is fine for me, but I'm having trouble finding necessary and/or sufficient conditions to show that these are the vertices of any triangle. I'm wondering if anyone knows some vector rule or theorem that I can use to show that these are the vertices of a triangle. Thanks.

Comment: Don't $3$ points in $\Bbb R^3$ *always* define a unique triangle (assuming they are the vertices of your triangle, of course)?  Just connect the $3$ points together by line segments and you've got a triangle.  Or are you concerned that they may not be in the same plane?

Comment: I didn't know that lol. Maybe you have just answered my question. So I don't have to show that they're a triangle at all, I can proceed to step 2 of my solution?

Comment: Yeah.  You just need to find the angles between those line segments (which you can represent with vectors) to make sure this is a *right* triangle.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Any three points not contained in a single line form a triangle. If points were contained in the same line, then their difference vectors would all be parallel.

Comment: Even if they're all collinear, you could just say they form a *degenerate* triangle (AKA a line segment).

Answer (score 2):

i computed the following vectors: $$\vec{AB}=(4,3,0)-(3,0,2) = (1,3,-2), \vec{AC} = (5,1,-3), \vec{BC}=(4, -2, -1). $$  now you see that $$ \vec{AB} \cdot \vec{BC} =(1,3,-2) \cdot (4, -2, -1) =1 \times 4 + 3 \times(-2) + (-2) \times (-1) = 0 .$$  therefore $$AB \perp BC$$ and the right angle is at $B.$

Answer (score 1):

Angle $B$: between vectors $\overrightarrow {BA}=(-1, -3, 2)$ & $\overrightarrow {BC}=(4, -2, -1)$ (heads directed away from the (origin) vertex B) is given as  $$\angle B=\cos^{-1}\left(\frac{(-1)(4)+(-3)(-2)+(2)(-1)}{\left(\sqrt{(-1)^2+(-3)^2+(2)^2}\right)\left(\sqrt{(4)^2+(-2)^2+(-1)^2}\right)}\right)$$$$=\cos^{-1}\left(\frac{0}{\sqrt{294}}\right)=\cos^{-1}\left(0\right)=90^o$$
Hence, $\Delta ABC$ is a right triangle with right angle at the vertex B ($\angle B=90^o$)